# Finding left most node in a binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I need to find the left most node in a binary tree. It may sound naive but it isnt. I tried this but i think it will fail :

```
Node* findLeftMostNode(Node* root){
    if(root->left==null)
       return root;
    findLeftMostNode(root->left);
}
```

The problem is that the left mode node can be at any level so we need to handle that.

```
          X
          \
           X
           /\
          X  X
         /
        X
       /
      X
```

Comment: Your diagram deceives you - the root node here is the left-most.  You might also think of this as "finding the minimum", to frame it more precisely.

Comment: Unless by some chance your problem specifically says otherwise, Dave is right. Other than that, you could theoretically keep track of left steps and right steps as you go down, returning the node and the horizontal position... but really, it's probably Dave's comment.

Comment: Imagine they have x,y coordinates , the one with the smallest x coordinate will be the left most node according to me. Does that specify what am trying to do ? And let root be 0,0

Comment: @Droider But how exactly are the coordinates computed? You need to precisely specify that (and you should have done that when you asked the question). Does each right edge add 1 to x and each left edge subtracts 1? Or something else?

Comment: And how does one determine how far 'left' a node is if you are using x,y coords?  Your link lines take space and will affect the left most display.

Comment: On going to right do x++ and on going left do x-- , So for the bottommost node , x = -2 (0->1->0->-1->-2 ) . hope that clarifies

Comment: Then pardon the obvious, but why aren't they sorted in the tree by said-(x,y) coordinates? What you're apparently asking for will require full enumeration of every node, and even then I am somewhat puzzled what the usefulness of such a search is really getting you.

Answer (score 3):

With this way of calculating the “leftness” of a node, you always have to recurse to both child nodes, because any child could contain a sequence of *n* nodes going left for any *n*.

So, the solution is actually quite simple: calculate the x for each node in the tree and return the smallest one:

```
Node* findLeftmostNode(Node* current, int x = 0)
{
    current->x = x;

    Node* best;
    // leftmost child in the left subtree is always better than the root
    if (current->left == null)
        best = current;
    else
        best = findLeftmostNode(current->left, x - 1);

    if (current->right != null)
    {
        Node* found = findLeftmostNode(current->right, x + 1);
        if (found->x < best->x)
            best = found;
    }

    return best;
}
```

Comment: I think this should be ok , I will get back after trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node *findLeftMostNode(Node* root){
    for( ; root; root =root->left)
    if (!root->left) break;
    }
  return root;
}
```